# Visual Studio 2015 Remote Debugging to Surface Pro 4: DEP4300 Could not generate root folder for app package

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, debugging, uwp

I am trying to remote debug from `Visual Studio 2015` to my `Surface Pro 4`. The connection appears to be fine (selected from Debug properties), but the deployment always fails with the following error:

> 1>DEP4300 : Could not generate the root folder for app package 599ee135-34ef-4d91-9dee-8ee51f442632|VS.Debug_x64.Nick_Alexander|CN=Nick Alexander|599ee135-34ef-4d91-9dee-8ee51f442632VS.Debug_x64.Nick_Alexander with base layout folder of C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles. Illegal characters in path.

I have spent an hour or so using Google to research the problem. Pretty much everyone says to just update the Remote Debugger tools to Visual Studio 2015 Update 3. I have updated the Remote Debugger Tools on both devices to the latest version that I can find a download for.

I have even tried repairing Visual Studio 2015. I am at a loss and have no idea how to proceed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by going to [Visual Studio Downloads](https://beta.visualstudio.com/downloads/), scrolling down to the Latest Releases search box, and searching for Remote Tools. I was then given the download for x64 Remote Tools Update 3. After installing and restarting, remote debugging is working.

Comment: thanks for sharing your solution, you could mark it as the answer.

Comment: @JackZhai I do intend to, but I am still not allowed to mark it as the answer for 12 more hours. I will after the waiting period.